# Change date format in a filename

Tags: powershell

I would like to mass rename a bunch of documents that have a data at the end of a filename.
Currently the format is DDMMYYYY and I would like to swap it to YYYYMMDD.
Would there be an "easy" way of modifying that for files with various filenames?  Each file name would always end in a date for the documents I want to modify.
Example would be 123456-newfile-DDMMYYYY.docx

I have seen a few similar posts that dealt with dates but neither of them would work in my scenario.
Any feedback would be most welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by solving the problem for a single file (see inline comments for explanation):

```
$file = Get-Item path\to\123456-newfile-17052022.docx

# start by splitting the file's basename (filename sans extension) 
# at the position immediately before the last 8 characters
$prefix, $datePart = $file.BaseName -split '(?=.{8}$)'

# test if the date-suffix is indeed a date in the expected format
$datetime = $null
if([datetime]::TryParseExact($datePart, 'ddMMyyyy', $null, $null, [ref]$datetime)){
    # we got a match, let's rename the file!
    $oldName = $file.Name
    $newName = '{0}{1:yyyyMMdd}{2}' -f $prefix,$datetime,$file.Extension
    $file |Rename-Item -NewName $newName
    Write-Host "Renamed file '${oldName}' to '${newName}'!"
}
```

Now that we have it solved for 1 file, solving it for multiple files can be achieved by simply wrapping the whole thing in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem path\to\files\*.docx -File){
    # start by splitting the file's basename (filename sans extension) 
    # at the position immediately before the last 8 characters
    $prefix, $datePart = $file.BaseName -split '(?=.{8}$)'
    
    # test if the date-suffix is indeed a date in the expected format
    $datetime = $null
    if([datetime]::TryParseExact($datePart, 'ddMMyyyy', $null, $null, [ref]$datetime)){
        # we got a match, let's rename the file!
        $oldName = $file.Name
        $newName = '{0}{1:yyyyMMdd}{2}' -f $prefix,$datetime,$file.Extension
        $file |Rename-Item -NewName $newName
        Write-Host "Renamed file '${oldName}' to '${newName}'!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an error:At line:9 char:82
+ ... ::TryParseExact($datePart, 'ddMMyyyy', $null, $null, [ref]$datetime){
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token '{' in expression or statement.
At line:9 char:82
+ ... ::TryParseExact($datePart, 'ddMMyyyy', $null, $null, [ref]$datetime){
+                                                                         ~

Comment: Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
At line:9 char:82
+ ... ::TryParseExact($datePart, 'ddMMyyyy', $null, $null, [ref]$datetime){
+                                                                         ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Where should the closing bracket go for "if" statement?

Comment: @LordJabol After `[ref]$datetime)` (I've fixed it now)

Comment: One step closer: Cannot find an overload for "TryParseExact" and the argument count: "5".
At line:9 char:4
+ if([datetime]::TryParseExact($datePart, 'ddMMyyyy', $null, $null, [re ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to your comment [Cannot find an overload for "TryParseExact" and the argument count: "5". At line:9 char:4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72272475/361842):

The issue is `$datetime = $null`.

Since the parameter expects a DateTime type, and DateTime is not nullable, the parameter can't be matched to a method signature.

Replace that with `$datetime = [DateTime]::MinValue` so you'll be using a valid DateTime value.

Similarly for the DateTimeStyles argument, use `'None'` or `[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None` instead of `$null`.